# Inheritance from Jobject Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Inheritance from Jobject(Newtonsoft) the existents properties from class not serialized.

Why were the Id and Name properties not serialized?

```
public class Test : JObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Test();
        test["new_pro"] = 123456;
        test.Id = 1;
        test.Name = "Dog";


        var r = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);

        // Result = { "new_pro":123456}

    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why inherit from JObject? Just make your own class and serialize that.

Comment: @krillgar I guess OP wants to be able to add dynamic properties to the object, which then begs the question: why have a custom class when JObject does the job?

Comment: Few properties are dynamic.

Answer (score 14):

Whatever is the reason you want to do that - the reason is simple: `JObject` implements `IDictionary` and this case is treated in a special way by Json.NET. If your class implements `IDictionary` - Json.NET will not look at properties of your class but instead will look for keys and values in the dictionary. So to fix your case you can do this:

```
public class Test : JObject
{
    public int Id
    {
        get { return (int) this["id"]; }
        set { this["id"] = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string) this["name"]; }
        set { this["name"] = value; }
    }
}
```

If you just want to have both dynamic and static properties on your object - there is no need to inherit from JObject. Instead, use `JsonExtensionData` attribute:

```
public class Test {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> AdditionalProperties { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();
}

var test = new Test();
test.AdditionalProperties["new_pro"] = 123456;
test.Id = 1;
test.Name = "Dog";            
var r = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
```

Comment: Hi this workaround is not a good idea for me. My class contains many properties (List, Nested Objects, etc)

Comment: Well then don't inherit from JObject or explain us why you absolutely must to do that, maybe we can find another workaround.

Comment: @Gus I've extended answer with one more option, probably that is what you need.

Comment: I decided look for this project.  [https://github.com/RickStrahl/Expando]. Thanks for you help. I need to create dynamic properties for a class.

Comment: [JsonExtensionData] is perfect! I was also working on a misguided attempt to inherit from JObject. This solution works great for me.