# How do you pass a derived JObject class in the body of a Web Api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, webapi

If I have the class

```
public class TestMe : JObject
{

}
```

How do I consume it within an API method?

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateMe(int accountId, [FromBody] TestMe sometest)
{
  Console.WriteLine(sometest);
  ...
```

When I try posting anything for the body, ex:

```
{
  "Bye": "string"
}
```

I get the following error before the `Console.WriteLine` line in the `UpdateMe` method is even hit:

```
"The parameters dictionary contains an invalid entry for parameter 'sometest' for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult] UpdateMe(Int32, TestMe)' in '<somepath>.Controllers.MiscController'. The dictionary contains a value of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject', but the parameter requires a value of type 'TestMe'."
```

Comment: Why are you extending JObject?

Comment: One method I sometimes use when working with generic Json object is to handle them as IDictionary<string, object> . Another way could be to simply read the raw request body as a string and deserialize it yourself. Perhaps you could achieve what you want with modelbinding but that will probably be a lot more work

Comment: There are many data types suited for getting dynamic data. A JObject isn't one of them. You are tying your API with a specific JSON library's object. Just use dynamic, or Dictionary, or any other type which suits you better.

Comment: Sorry you accept my answer but gave the bounty to the other answer. Is that correct?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ yes, this was the first time I've ever done the bounty thing and it had a bounty button next to both of your answers so I thought I would be able to award to both, but after I awarded the first answer, your bounty button disappeared :(

Comment: thanks, it is to sad not getting 250 bounty, but that is fine the other guy get it. thanks informing me 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer NOT possible, IMO what you are asking for is NOT possible and has not thing to do with api.

IMO you have 3 options either use

- dynamic type
- custom object type
- Dictionay type

As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203358/inheritance-from-jobject-newtonsoft) mention,

> Whatever is the reason you want to do that - the reason is simple:
> JObject implements IDictionary and this case is treated in a special
> way by Json.NET. If your class implements IDictionary - Json.NET will
> not look at properties of your class but instead will look for keys
> and values in the dictionary. So to fix your case you can do this

Let's get some details:

To prove my first point, try just to create a simple console app with newton.json with your input as string:

```
var input = "{\"Bye\": \"string\"}";
```

With dynamic it will works fine:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(input);
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
```

Now with customize object like:

```
public class TestMe
{
    public string Bye { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestMe>(input);
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
```

Works fine as well.

Now lets take your approach:

```
public class TestMe : JObject
{
    
}
```

Testing it with following, it will break:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestMe>(input);
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
```

Now lets try with Dictionary:

```
public class TestMe
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> MyProperties { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();
}
```

And test it

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestMe>(input);
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
```

Will also works fine.

Now I have presented 3 options.

Answer (score 4):

the controller can't accept a class that inherits directly from the `JObject` class. ([more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203358/inheritance-from-jobject-newtonsoft)). I assume that in your case you don't know what properties you will receive in your input JSON. These are possible solutions:

Accept only the `JObject` class in your controller.

```cs
[Route("{accountID}")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateMe(int accountId, [FromBody] JObject sometest)
{
    string test = sometest.ToString();

    return Ok(test);
}
```

you can work with the `JObject` class as you wish. Example - [read more here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JObjectProperties.htm).
This is one solution to the problem.

---

Another solution will be to read the JSON body as a raw JSON and do it whatever your needs may be:

```cs
[Route("{accountID}")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateMe(int accountId)
{
    string rawContent = string.Empty;
    using (var contentStream = await this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        contentStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(contentStream))
        {
            rawContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
            // use raw content here
        }
    }

    return Ok(rawContent);
}
```

---

Another solution for an unknown input JSON is to accept the `dynamic` type in the controller, but personally, I don't recommend that. How to implement it [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774860/asp-net-web-api-not-binding-to-dynamic-object-on-post). Why I don't like it, [check this here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859016/is-the-use-of-dynamic-considered-a-bad-practice)

---